# What are the differences between ssh generated keys(ssh-keygen) and OpenSSL keys (PEM)and what is more secure for ssh remote login?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, ssh, openssl

I have learned there are 2 methods to make SSH remote login easier and secure , those are;

1. ssh generated keys (using ssh-keygen)[OpenSSH Keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)
2. PEM (.pem) keys usually generated with OpenSSL (Amazon Web Services uses this method) [OpenSSL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL)

my question is that what are the differences of these 2 methods which one is more secure and why is it more secure ?

Comment: [Generate your SSH keys with openssl](http://serverfault.com/questions/358239/choosing-the-encryption-algorithm-used-by-osx-ssh-keygen/358247#358247) if you like.  The only part that is special is the public key.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The file format is different but they both encode the same kind of keys. Moreover, they are both generated with the same code: `openssl` (the command-line tool) is a wrapper around [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) (the library), and [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.org/) actually uses OpenSSL (the library) for its cryptographic operations, including key pair generation. So there is no *direct* security difference.

We could argue a bit about password-based encryption of the private keys, but there is nothing really significant here.

Comment: Something that is confusing me about `pem` files is that _are they the private key? the public key? or both?_ When we run `openssl rsa -in in.pem -pubout out.pub`, what does happen under the hood? Is the public key extracted from the PEM file or is the PEM file used to generate a public key?

Comment: "PEM" mostly means "some binary object encoded in Base64, with an explicit header `-----BEGIN XXX-----` and footer `-----END XXX-----` that indicates the object type". Private keys are not the only type of data that can use PEM format; e.g. certificates and CRL can too. **That being said**, most private key format includes a copy of the public key, or the public key can be easily recomputed from the private key, so you can think of "the private key file" as "the file that contains the public _and_ the private key".

Comment: When the PEM file looks like this: `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- ... -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, I assume it only contains the private key and when we use `openssl rsa -in sample.pem -out sample.pub.der -outform DER -pubout` it computes the public key, is that correct?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are generating same-size RSA keys for both, there is no difference other than file format. Using one or another will mean absolutely nothing in terms of their effect on security.